# Extraer nombre de dominio con expresión regular

Tags: regex, perl

¿Cómo puedo extraer sólo el dominio de una URL? O sea, que busque en lo siguiente:

```
www.google.com
yahoo.com/something
fnetworkings.meatmarket.co.uk?someparameter
https://josh.meatmarket.co.uk/asldf/asdf
roxmedianetwork.com
roxy-n2.gq
http://1dollaradz.com/tw1k3steps-splash-page-copy/ir-msg
http://2012.zzz.com.ua
http://2017reset.sitey.me
http://240.112.0.101.static.digitalpacific.com.au/administrator/images/alibaba/alibaba/index.php
https://www.example.com
```

y que extraiga sólo la parte del dominio:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
meatmarket.co.uk
meatmarket.co.uk
roxmedianetwork.com
roxy-n2.gq
1dollaradz.com
zzz.com.ua
sitey.me
digitalpacific.com.au
example.com
```

Tengo esta expresión regular:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:((www|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.))?([^:\/\n\?\=]+)
```

Pero sólo está capturando el final cuando la URL no tiene subdominio.

---

```
sub check_url_dominio {

my ( $self, $msg ) = @_;
my $check_https     = lc( $msg->get('body') );

#Archivo 01 - Domain
open d1, "/root/phishing-domains-ACTIVE.txt";

#Archivo 02 - Links
open l1, "/root/phishing-links-ACTIVE.txt";

Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::dbg("check_url_dominio'$check_https");


$check_url_full = qr/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:((www|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.))?([^:\/\n\?\=]+)/im;

Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::dbg($check_https);

if ( $check_https =~ $check_url_full ) {
    foreach $dominio( <d1> ){
        if( $check_https == $dominio ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    foreach $link( <l1> ){
        if( $check_https == $link ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y qué tiene de malo ese regex? En qué te falló?

Comment: En si como podría hacer verificar que dentro de un texto exista una url, por ejemplo: evaluar un mensaje de correo
quieres mas info click aqui http://zitara.com y ahi es donde 
debería evaluar, determinar y extraer el dominio para luego compararlo con una lista de dominios y urls o links que esta en un archivo. Tambien puede ser que sea https://www.zitara.com

Comment: Y cómo lo estás intentando usar en perl (no entiendo la etiqueta PHP)? Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/403928/edit) la prgeunta para añadir código e info adicional que ayude a aclarar tu problema. Código en los comentarios es generalmente mala idea :)

Comment: Agregare una respuesta. Hice esto ne Perl por mientras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El dominio está antes del [TLD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominio_de_nivel_superior). El tema es identificar los secundarios como en `.com.ar`, `.com.ua`, etc.

Si nos permitimos tomar como secundario a cualquiera que tenga 2 o 3 caracteres, entonces:

```
m<^(?:\w+://)?+(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?+(?:\w(?:[-\w]{0,61}\w)?\.)*?(\w(?:[-\w]{0,61}\w)?\.(?:\w{2,3}\.)?\w{1,10})(?:[/?#]|$)>gm
```

Pero claro, esto fallaría con algo como `subdominio.un.com`. Si llega a ser un problema, podrías obtener un listado completo de ccTLDs (de países), o agregar excepciones para dominios de 2 o 3 caracteres.

Explicado muy brevemente:

- `(?:\w+://)?+` protocolo (por ejemplo `http://`)
- `(?:[^@\n]+@)?` credenciales (por ejemplo `user:pass@`
- `(?:www\.)?+` si tiene `www.` que coincida de forma atómica (si coincide, no permite que sea parte del dominio)
- `(?:\w(?:[-\w]{0,61}\w)?\.)*?` subdominios (entre 1 y 63 caracteres seguidos de un punto)
- `\w(?:[-\w]{0,61}\w)?\.` dominio (ídem anterior pero ahora ya adentro del grupo 1)
- `(?:\w{2,3}\.)?` secundario (ejemplo `com.` en `.com.ar`)
- `\w{1,10}` TLD (ejemplo `.org`)
- `(?:[/?#]|$)` termina en `/`, `?`, `#` o el final de la línea.